# No arrows when using Graph[]

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks

I have the following code in Mathematica:

```
mp = DiscreteMarkovProcess[{1, 0, 0}, ({
     {0.6, 0.1, 0.3},
     {0.2, 0.7, 0.1},
     {0.3, 0.3, 0.4}
    })];
Graph[mp]
```

[image]

However, when it plots the graph, there are no arrows on the edges. Could someone tell me what option enables the arrows to be displayed?

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of MMA are you using? In 10.4 there *are* arrows on the edges.

Comment: I also cannot reproduce this behavior on version 11.3 for macOS.

Comment: I'm using MMA 10.0.1 on MacOS

Comment: in version 9.0 (windows) and in version 11.3 (wolfram cloud) it works fine.

Comment: I can reproduce your results in version 10.0.2, 10.1.0, and 10.2.0 with macOS. The arrowheads appear with version 10.3.1

Comment: does `Graph[mp, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]` give the desired result?

Comment: Next time please indicate the version of Mathematica you are using with problems like this (unless it is the latest version).

Comment: @kglr Hello. Yes. Thank you that worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
Graph[mp, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
```

as a workaround.

Comment: Hello. Thank you. That worked! I couldn't find this in the documentation anywhere, maybe didn't look hard enough? :)

Comment: @ThomasMoore This option will cause the arrowtip positions to adapt to the shape of the vertex, even if it is not circular. I learned it from a Wolfram developer on this forum. I do not know whether (or where) it is found in the documentation.